# What are some familiar expressions can I use to mean someone is lucky?

Tags: expressions

I am in a context where I would need a familiar (but not vulgar) short expression that means someone is lucky. Can someone help?

Comment: There's [lucky duck](http://blogs.mbgsd.org/aclark/just-ducky-idioms-expressions-of-duck-origin/), if you want something rather informal. (I'm not sure how universally recognized that is, but I've heard it off-and-on since I was a kid).

Comment: On reflection I think the question isn't really constructive. Given that there's not really such a thing as "continuous luck" I suspect almost ***every*** way of  referring to someone's "luckiness" may be tinged with overtones of envy/jealousy (depending on speaker and context, of course).

Answer (score 2):

You can say "fortunate", "lucky", "leading a charmed life", "favored of the gods", "smiled upon by Providence", some of those being overly quaint for modern conversation.

Answer (score 2):

You could say:

> *hit gold*
>
> *lucky duck*
>
> *lucky dog*
>
> *lucked out* (US meaning; in the UK *lucked out* means *had **bad** luck*)
>
> *blessed*
>
> *hit the jackpot*
>
> *struck it rich* (whether or not the luck is monetary)
>
> *has the luck of the Irish*
>
> *his ship came in*
>
> *his horse came in*
>
> *sitting pretty*

Comment: "Sitting pretty" is a great fit for my context. Thanks!

Comment: @zneak: If that's the case, your question text didn't explain what you wanted very clearly. *Sitting pretty* simply means *in a good position* - which could just as easily have come about through diligent planning and hard word as by "luck".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, then, indeed, that's not really what I want. I guess I was a little too enthusiast and should have checked the precise meaning of it. If you have better ideas for expressions, feel free to post them.

Comment: @zneak: All bib's other suggestions are fine (except *lucked **out***, which to me **as a Brit** means *had **bad** luck*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - agreed. the Urban Dictionary says, in regard to lucked out "In the UK this has the exact opposite meaning to that in the USA."